# Quarkus opentracing Traced annotation

Tags: java, annotations, quarkus, open-telemetry, opentracing

Quick question. Does the @Traced annotation still work? This was part of Quarkus's opentracing which is now replaced with the opentelemetry implementation. I am wondering if the @Traced is supposed to work as i tried it on a call but it doesn't generate any traces. I just wanted to confirm it's because of the migration to opentelemetry and not due to something missing..

Thank you in advance!

SG

Comment: No, `@Traced` is not supported with OpenTelemetry. The corresponding annotation is `@WithSpan`.

Comment: Thanks. and I guess we need to do this on every method we want to include as opposed to traced which was done at the class level?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think that's correct.

Comment: OK Thank you for the confirmation!

Comment: @Ladicek sounds like a proper answer :)

Comment: 100% Agree with the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by [Ladicek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/742081/ladicek), the old `quarkus-smallrye-opentracing` annotation `@Traced`, was replaced by `@WithSpan` in methods when using the newer `quarkus-opentelemetry` extension.

It can be used together with `@SpanAttribute` to store method arguments as span attributes.

Please see: https://quarkus.io/guides/opentelemetry#cdi

Comment: Yes. Thank you!